# How to strip data out of html code in MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

I have a table in MYSQL that looks like this **(notice the html code)**:

```
===================================================================|
|           Question                         |   Answer            |
=========+===========+=============================================|
| <p> Do you listen to music? </p>           |        YES          |            
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Who is your favorite music artists?        | Justin Beiber       | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|<script>Are you a Male or female?</script>  |      M              | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I am using PHPExcel in PHP to extract that data and place it in an excel file, and that table is what my excel file looks like.

In excel I want the html removed so that the fields only contain the question:

```
===================================================================|
|           Question                         |   Answer            |
=========+===========+=============================================|
|     Do you listen to music?                |        YES          |            
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Who is your favorite music artists?        | Justin Beiber       | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      Are you a Male or female?             |      M              | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

**The code in PHP:**

```
$col=1; // 1-based index
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$row= 1;

    foreach ($row_data as $key=>$value) {

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
$row++;
    }
    $col++;

}

$row=1;
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
$col=0;

    foreach($row_data as $value) {

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $row++;

    $col++;}
}
```

Comment: Is this question the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243332 ?

Comment: No, that question is how to remove a row with html. This is just about stripping the html and leaving the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, strip_tags($value));
```

This is a good example of why HTM should not be mixed with content in a database

Comment: You're right about that. I didn't think it would be so easy. Thanks!